# Inverse probability weights in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply inverse probability weights to a regression, but `lm()` only uses analytic weights.  This is part of a replication I'm working on where the original author is using `pweight` in Stata, but I'm trying to replicate it in R.  The analytic weights are providing lower standard errors which is causing problems with some of my variable being significance.

I've tried looking at the `survey` package, but am not sure how to prepare a survey object for use with `svyglm()`.  Is this the approach I want, or is there an easier way to apply inverse probability weights?

dput :

```
data <- structure(list(lexptot = c(9.1595012302023, 9.86330744180814, 
8.92372556833205, 8.58202430280175, 10.1133857229336), progvillm = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), sexhead = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), agehead = c(79L, 
43L, 52L, 48L, 35L), weight = c(1.04273509979248, 1.01139605045319, 
1.01139605045319, 1.01139605045319, 0.76305216550827)), .Names = c("lexptot", 
"progvillm", "sexhead", "agehead", "weight"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Linear Model (using analytic weights)

```
prog.lm <- lm(lexptot ~ progvillm + sexhead + agehead, data = data, weight = weight)
summary(prog.lm)
```

Comment: Haven't used it before, but a search on RSeek turned up [the ipw package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v43/i13/paper). It's not currently on CRAN, but you could install an archived version.

Comment: @Gregor I've looked at that package, but being that it's out of data and not available in CRAN I didn't think of installing.  Also, it appears that `survey` has taken it's place, but I can't figure out how to get the object for regression.

Comment: it is worth mentioning that the `survey` package does not only use  inverse probability weights, but more importantly also accounts for design based standard errors. `pweights` alone are also implemented in the 'glm' function and there is no need to use the survey package if you do not need design based standard errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, so I figured it out and thought I would update the post incase others were trying to figure it out.  It's actually pretty straightforward.

```
data$X <- 1:nrow(data)
des1 <- svydesign(id = ~X,  weights = ~weight, data = data)
prog.lm <- svyglm(lexptot ~ progvillm + sexhead + agehead, design=des1)
summary(prog.lm)
```

Standard errors are now correct.

Comment: Are you sure it is correct? The `id` argument is for specifying clustered designs. Id should be `~0` or `~1` for simple random designs.

Comment: @Michał Yes this is correct.  The standard errors are now correct.  I don't see the need to `id`, but if you have a suggestion please provide an answer.

Comment: This topic is two years old, but it is useful :) I will add that that `svydesign(id = ~1, ...)` is simplier and produces exactly the same results!