# How to specify sampling weights (inverse probability weights) in a binomial mixed effect model or GEE

Tags: r

I'm looking at specifying inverse probability weights associated with each data point in a data frame (not [analytical weights](http://docs.displayr.com/wiki/Category:Weights)) for a mixed effect logistic regression for use vs. available GPS locations from animals. My question is closely related to this post: ([Inverse probability weights in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445295/inverse-probability-weights-in-r)), but for a mixed-effect model. The svyglm function specifies the correct weights, but the survey package doesn't allow for random effects, and lme4 uses analytical weights. I looked into the coxme package as an alternative but the help file indicates that weights are specified as per lm, which uses analytical weights.

Is there a package/function implemented in r to specify sampling weights for mixed effects, or a way to specify sampling weights using the coxme package?

example data:

```
data2 <- structure(list(Use = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AnimalID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), St.A1k = c(0.029627, 0.043414, 
0.113816, 0.000000, 0.020241, 0.000000,0.000000, 0.007334, 0.000000, 
0.046055, 0.028454, 0.042828, 0.018480, 0.106776, 0.018480, 0.046641, 
0.033148, 0.039308, 0.035494, 0.000000, 0.004987, 0.051335, 0.046935, 
0.018774, 0.000000, 0.043708, 0.014667, 0.080375, 0.000000, 0.015254, 
0.000000, 0.053388, 0.055148, 0.036668, 0.006160, 0.016720, 0.029041, 
0.057788, 0.023174, 0.022294, 0.031388, 0.043414, 0.005573, 0.000000, 
0.024054,0.000000, 0.000000, 0.074215, 0.021121, 0.016720, 0.028454, 
0.042828, 0.018480, 0.106776, 0.018480, 0.046641, 0.033148, 0.039308, 
0.035494, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.053388, 0.055148, 0.036668, 0.006160, 
0.016720, 0.029041, 0.057788, 0.023174, 0.022294,0.031388, 0.043414, 
0.005573, 0.000000, 0.024054, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.074215, 0.021121, 
0.016720, 0.029627, 0.043414, 0.113816, 0.000000, 0.020241, 0.000000, 
0.000000, 0.007334, 0.000000, 0.046055, 0.029627, 0.043414, 0.113816, 
0.000000, 0.020241, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.007334, 0.000000, 0.046055), 
InvWeight = c(1.332636, 1.248722, 1.248722, 1.248722, 1.179661, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1.060296, 1.060296, 1.249593, 1.248595, 1.248626, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1.294132, 1.740839, 1.740839, 2.377546, 2.377546, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2.378091,2.378091, 2.378091, 2.378091, 1.060295, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.060296, 
1.060296, 1.249593, 1.248595, 1.248626, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.378091, 2.378091, 
2.378091, 2.378091, 1.060295, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.378091, 2.378091, 2.378091, 
2.378091, 1.060295, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.294132,1.740839, 1.740839, 2.377546, 
2.377546, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.332636, 1.248722, 1.248722, 1.248722, 1.179661, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.060296,1.060296, 1.249593, 1.248595, 1.248626, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1)),.Names = c("Use", "Status", "AnimalID", "St.A1k", "InvWeight"), class = 
c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

## GLM with sampling weights

```
des2 <- svydesign(id = ~1,  weights = ~InvWeight, data = data2)
glm.sampling.weights <- svyglm(Use ~ St.A1k, family = binomial, design=des2)
summary(glm.sampling.weights)
```

## GLM (not sampling weights)

```
glm.w <- glm(Use ~ St.A1k, family = binomial, weight=InvWeight, data=data2)
summary(glm.w)
```

(from the glm help file: "For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes").

## GEE

```
cox.w <- coxme(Surv(Status,Use) ~ St.A1k + (1|AnimalID), weight=InvWeight, 
data=data2)
summary(cox.w)
```

Comment: did you end up finding an answer for your question? you can apply IPWs to GEE in geepack, and cox models as pooled logistic regression (https://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/116267/2/sjart_st0075.pdf). I found your question because I was trying to find why IPW "can't" be used with mixed models - GEE is advised but not based on any citeable evidence as far as I can find.